# kubeadm init stuck with proxy and forbidden errors

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, init, kubeadm

I have spent two days trying to initialize my master node for kubernetes on my virtual machine.

I have no idea what the issue is, i am getting a few "forbidden" and "connection refused" errors

I also have setup my http_proxy env var as follows:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://proxy-ip:port/
$ export https_proxy=http://proxy-ip:port/
```

My kubeadm version:

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.3", GitCommit:"d2835416544f298c919e2ead3be3d0864b52323b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-02-07T11:55:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Whenever i do a:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

I get this result:

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.9.3
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
    [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
    [WARNING HTTPProxy]: Connection to "https://IP:6443" uses proxy "http://proxy-ip:port". If that is not intended, adjust your proxy settings
    [WARNING HTTPProxyCIDR]: connection to "10.96.0.0/12" uses proxy "http://proxy-ip:port". This may lead to malfunctional cluster setup. Make sure that Pod and Services IP ranges specified correctly as exceptions in proxy configuration
    [WARNING HTTPProxyCIDR]: connection to "10.244.0.0/16" uses proxy "http://proxy-ip:port". This may lead to malfunctional cluster setup. Make sure that Pod and Services IP ranges specified correctly as exceptions in proxy configuration
[preflight] Starting the kubelet service
[certificates] Generated ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver certificate and key.
[certificates] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [mydns kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 IP]
[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "scheduler.conf"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-apiserver to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-controller-manager to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-scheduler to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[etcd] Wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd instance to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
[init] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests".
[init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.
```

...and it gets stuck there. Here are my kubelet logs

```
Feb 22 11:17:30   kubelet: E0222 11:17:30.486017    3983 summary.go:92] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/kubelet.service": failed to get cgroup stats for "/system.slice/kubelet.service": failed to get container info for "/system.slice/kubelet.service": unknown container "/system.slice/kubelet.service"
Feb 22 11:17:30   kubelet: E0222 11:17:30.486054    3983 summary.go:92] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get cgroup stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get container info for "/system.slice/docker.service": unknown container "/system.slice/docker.service"
Feb 22 11:17:30   kubelet: W0222 11:17:30.491931    3983 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Feb 22 11:17:30   kubelet: E0222 11:17:30.492066    3983 kubelet.go:2104] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.272564       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.273579       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.273635       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1beta1.StatefulSet: Get https://IP:6443/apis/apps/v1beta1/statefulsets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.273689       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.275024       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.275173       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.275200       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: Get https://IP:6443/apis/policy/v1beta1/poddisruptionbudgets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.275314       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/server.go:590: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.schedulerName%3Ddefault-scheduler%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.275318       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1beta1.ReplicaSet: Get https://IP:6443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/replicasets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:35   kubelet: W0222 11:17:35.492831    3983 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Feb 22 11:17:35   kubelet: E0222 11:17:35.493249    3983 kubelet.go:2104] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
Feb 22 11:17:36   journal: E0222 16:17:36.189616       1 leaderelection.go:224] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:39   journal: E0222 16:17:39.278107       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:39   journal: E0222 16:17:39.278220       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:39   journal: E0222 16:17:39.278320       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1beta1.ReplicaSet: Get https://IP:6443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/replicasets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:39   journal: E0222 16:17:39.278556       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1beta1.StatefulSet: Get https://IP:6443/apis/apps/v1beta1/statefulsets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:39   journal: E0222 16:17:39.278665       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:39   journal: E0222 16:17:39.278953       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:39   journal: E0222 16:17:39.279453       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:39   journal: E0222 16:17:39.279748       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/server.go:590: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.schedulerName%3Ddefault-scheduler%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:39   journal: E0222 16:17:39.282080       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: Get https://IP:6443/apis/policy/v1beta1/poddisruptionbudgets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
Feb 22 11:17:40   kubelet: W0222 11:17:40.493931    3983 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Feb 22 11:17:40   kubelet: E0222 11:17:40.494041    3983 kubelet.go:2104] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

Whenever I look at my docker ps, I see the api-server going up then shutting down.

Comment: I want to add that it seems to block after it downloads and runs the controller image in docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with a no_proxy env variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an issue with kubeadm that use wrong proxy, don't try to modify your environment variable with

export http_proxy= .....

Because kubeadm don't take into account these variables. kubeadm look at /etc/environment to find the proxy to use. So declare your proxy in /etc/environment

(based on my own experience)

Comment: yes, environment should place in `/etc/environment`, i fixed `WARNING HTTPProxyCIDR` after setting env in the file.

Answer (score 1):

### Failed to get system container stats:

```
Feb 22 11:17:30   kubelet: E0222 11:17:30.486017    3983 summary.go:92] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/kubelet.service": failed to get cgroup stats for "/system.slice/kubelet.service": failed to get container info for "/system.slice/kubelet.service": unknown container "/system.slice/kubelet.service"
Feb 22 11:17:30   kubelet: E0222 11:17:30.486054    3983 summary.go:92] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get cgroup stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get container info for "/system.slice/docker.service": unknown container "/system.slice/docker.service"
```

- [kubelet fails to get cgroup stats for docker and kubelet services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726216/kubelet-fails-to-get-cgroup-stats-for-docker-and-kubelet-services)

Make sure the cgroup of kubelet and docker is the same.

```
docker info | grep -i cgroup
cat /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

If different, then update /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf to set the docker's cgroup to kubelet. Look for **cgroup-driver** in the file. Need to reload/restart the kubelet systemd service.

Please refer to  [Troubleshooting kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/) and understand all there will help a lot.

### Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/nodes

```
Feb 22 11:17:30   kubelet: W0222 11:17:30.491931    3983 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Feb 22 11:17:30   kubelet: E0222 11:17:30.492066    3983 kubelet.go:2104] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
Feb 22 11:17:33   journal: E0222 16:17:33.272564       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://IP:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
```

Please make sure correct cluster API Server IP is set.

```
https://**IP**:6443/api/v1/nodes <----- "**IP"** should be the API server IP address?
```

To explicitly specify:

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=<The IP of the API server>
```

Please refer to [kubeadm init - options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#options) and [Initializing your master](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#24-initializing-your-master).

### kubeadm reset

Perhaps need to re-install the cluster. kubeadm reset only will not let you re-run kubeadm init and recreate cluster as expected. Need to manually clean up overlay network files, etc.

Please refer to ["Failed to setup network for pod \ using network plugins \"cni\": no IP addresses available in network: podnet; Skipping pod"](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39557)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Unfortunately both cgroup were the same on both Kubernetes and Docker.Also yes, the "IP" is the API-server IP. I have inputed my DHCP generated IP. Of course, a cleanup is done before every kubeadm init.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726216/kubelet-fails-to-get-cgroup-stats-for-docker-and-kubelet-services