# kubeadm init stuck at "Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

kubeadm init stuck at "Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane"

In pre-flight I see the following warning

```
connection to "10.96.0.0/12" uses proxy "http://127.0.0.1:45007". This may lead to malfunctional cluster setup. Make sure that Pod and Services IP ranges specified correctly as exceptions in proxy configuration .
```

I use kubernetes **v1.15**,
My swap is off, 
Docker runtime has been set it correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubeadm init stuck with proxy and forbidden errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934388/kubeadm-init-stuck-with-proxy-and-forbidden-errors)

Comment: It's a new cluster or you are adding nodes to an old cluster? What Linux distribution? Can you detail the steps you followed and what you already tried?

Comment: @mWatney  it's a new cluster, my Ubuntu version is 18.04. my docker version is 18.09, swap is off, kubernetes version 1.15. I have followed the following documentation https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/kubernetes/kubernetes-upstream/index.html.    When I was debugging I found systemctl enable kubelet.service is not working, cni is not available, so when I tried to install I'm getting a connection error

Comment: What else you did besides what is described in the documentation you shared? I followed it and it's working fine. Are you using proxy or something? Please describe your setup as much as you can.

Comment: @mWatney I'm using a proxy